# Error 1064 : SQL syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

I have a SQL code in a java code which looks like this :

```
    Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        beforeExerTestDTO dto = new beforeExerTestDTO();

        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
        sql.append(" select * ");
        sql.append(" from n_before_exer ");
        sql.append(" where id=?");
        sql.append("    and reg_date = (select max(reg_date) from n_before_exer where id=?)");

        try {
            con = pool.getLocalConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            pstmt.setString(1, id);
            pstmt.setString(2, id);
            System.out.println("여기까진 살까??");
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            /......
            ...... some code /
            }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("read : " + e);
            System.out.println("read : " + sql);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("read : " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }finally{
            DBClose.close(con, pstmt, rs);
        }
        return dto;
}
```

When the file gets executed it forms a statement like this in console:

```
select *  from n_before_exer  where id=?    and reg_date = (select max(reg_date) from n_before_exer where id=?)
```

and throws a

> java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION

What I tried :

1. I ran the same in Mysql Workbench query :

and got the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '?  and reg_date = (select max(reg_date) from
>   n_before_exer where id=?)' at line 1

A bit of research on the topic shows :

1. This way is not a preferred way as it can lead to injection attacks
2. And was advised to use a placeholder for a parameter

It seems a bit complex for me, if anyone can help me construct this statement in the right preferred way please

Thanks

Comment: Are you replacing the "?" With a parameter before execute the query?

Comment: @DanteFañaBadia : Added extra code around the error statement. Can you see if it confirms what you are saying

Comment: I thinks is a problem with parameter , the parameter apparently  doesn't set correctly try put ' around the ? , Just for debugging propose.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a prepared statement:

```
Connection con; // get a connection
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, someInt);
ps.setInt(2, someOtherInt);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // process each record
}
```

Comment: I added the extra code before and after the SQL error statement. I guess am already doing what you asked me to. Can you have a look at the updated question. Thanks

Comment: Where do you actually create the connection?  I don't see this happening anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement seem correct in syntax. Are you have encoding issue on you java file?

Comment: Kevin the file uses a UTF-8, but data can be Korean too. I guess it was working before, only on this local setup its acting wierd.

Comment: I just think if there is fullwidth character in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

pstmt.setString(1, id);

I guess the problem is that the type of id is not string ,you could use this to have a try: